# .writerow() csv returns a number instead of writing rows

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am testing some really simple code with Python 3. For some reason, the following code generates an empty output, instead of writing a line

```python
import csv

output = open('hello world.csv', 'w',newline='')
wr = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

wr.writerow('hello world')
```

If I try the commands in the interpreter,  `.writerow()` returns a number. The following example is the one used in the [documentation page](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/csv.html):

```python
>> import csv
>>> spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline=''), delimiter=' ',
... quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
>>> spamWriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
40
>>> spamWriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
37
```

Answer (score 9):

`writerow` actually writes rows but you don't see them in `eggs.csv` because of file buffering. To see something in the file close it or call `.flush()` method. If you use `with`-statement then the file is closed automatically even if there is an error.

It is not documented ([report a bug?](http://bugs.python.org/)) but `writerow` returns the result of `fileobj.write()` method i.e. number of characters written to a file in this case.

You should pass a sequence of fields that form a row to `writerow` method:

```
writer.writerow(['field 1', 'field 2', 'etc'])
```

If you pass a string instead of a list then the string is interpreted as a sequence of fields where each field is an individual character:

```
#XXX this is probably not what you want, don't do it
writer.writerow('abc')
# -> a,b,c
```

Comment: Is it possible to suppress the return of `number of characters` when using `writer.writerow(list)`? I was wondering this because if it's a big file, the python terminal gets filled up with numbers. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: @bioinfoboy: to suppress output, assign to a dummy variable: `_ = writer.writerow(row)`